# Yii2 CacheSession создает сессию в $_SESSION и в кеше одновременно

Tags: php, yii2

Случайно заметил такой нюанс при использования хранилища сессий в кеше ( в моем случае memcached ) Yii2 создает одновременно ее же и в массиве $_SESSION, хотя по логике не должен его использовать если в настройках указывается другое хранилище

Конфиг: ( пример - http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-cachesession.html )

```
'cache' => [
        'class' => 'yii\caching\MemCache',
        'useMemcached' => TRUE,
        'servers' => [
            [   
               'host' => '******/.system/memcache/socket',
               'port' => 11211,
               'weight' => 64,
           ],

       ]
    ],
    'session' => [
        'class' => 'yii\web\CacheSession',
       // 'cache' => 'cache',
    ],
```

Создание сессии:

```
    $session = Yii::$app->session;
    $userDataStorage = [
        'id'        => $this->id,
        'name'      => $this->name,
        'settings'  => json_decode($this->settings),          
    ];
    $session->set('user_data' , $userDataStorage);
```

Проверяем:

```
        echo 'Yii session -> ';
            var_dump(Yii::$app->session->get('user_data')  );
            echo '------------- <br/>';
        echo 'Php session -> ';
            var_dump($_SESSION);
            echo '------------- <br/>';
            var_dump(ini_get('session.save_path'));
```

Видим:

```
     Yii session -> array(4) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(1)
      ["name"]=>
      string(5) "admin"
      ["settings"]=>
      NULL
    }
    ------------- 
    Php session -> array(3) {
      ["__flash"]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["__id"]=>
      int(1)
      ["user_data"]=>
      array(4) {
        ["id"]=>
        int(1)
        ["name"]=>
        string(5) "admin"
        ["settings"]=>
        NULL
      }
    }

    ------------- 
    string(24) "****/.system/tmp"
```

Собственно это баг или... ? В чем тогда смысль настройки хранения сессий в кеше если он дублируется со стандартным ? Или я что-то делаю не так?

**СОРРИ не доглядел.** https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/web/Session.php методом **registerSessionHandler() устанавливает session_set_save_handler** а класс "CacheSession" реализует методы которые будут хранить сессию в кеше определенном в настройках, т.о. $_SESSION хранится уже не в файле папки tmp (как по умолчанию) а в memcached. Вопрос закрыт.

Comment: А я что-то не увидел использование `memcache`, собственно.......что-то мне кажется вы просто в сессию и сохраняете.. а для использования кэшСессии нужно действовать по-другому. вот пример `redis` https://gitlab.com/yoage/yii2-redis

Comment: Нет, все правильно настроено и работает, настройки в первом куске кода. Так же проверял отдельным подключением к memcached серверу данные сессии там есть, единственный момент что Yii2 шифрует ключ ( метод buildKey, http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-caching-cache.html#buildKey%28%29-detail , https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/caching/Cache.php стр. 83 ) поэтому с первого раза не просто ее найти отдельно от фреймворка. Я бы с радостью заюзал Redis но пока нет такой возможности

Comment: Думаю можно как ответ сделать и там более подробно описать где этот `registerSessionHandler` вызывается к примеру и т.д.  Возможно будет полезен кому ответ. А иначе проще удалить вопрос))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Возможно будет кому-то полезно, тогда начну сначала.
Как настроить кеширование Yii2 для работы с memcache или memcache**d** ( в чем отличия я думаю тут описывать нет смысла, в нете масса инфы по этому поводу ), постараюсь кратко изложить саму суть. Итак, для начала
заходим в файл конфигурации проэкта и добавляем настройки кеширования и подключения к серверу

```
    'components' => [

     ...

        'cache' => [
                'class' => 'yii\caching\MemCache', 
                'useMemcached' => TRUE,
                'servers' => [
                    [   
                       'host' => 'localhost',
                       'port' => 11211,
                       'weight' => 64,
                   ],

               ]
            ],

     ...
    ]
```

Параметр 'useMemcached' ( класс MemCache расположен в директории yii2/caching/MemCache.php ( наследуется от компонента Cache /yii2/caching/Cache.php ) и по умолчанию FALSE, т.е. юзает memcache ) указывает на то что будет использоватся memcache или memcache**d**,
для использования memcache**d** ставим в конфиге 'useMemcached' => TRUE 
Далее если все верно настроено прописано можем юзать кеш

```
\Yii::$app->cache->set('key', 'value');
\Yii::$app->cache->get('key');

//или можем кешировать запросы в БД

$db = Yii::$app->db;
    $result = $db->cache(function ($db) { 
        return $db->createCommand('SELECT * FROM tablename LIMIT 0,1000')->queryAll();
    });
// и т.д.
****
```

Подробнее в доке http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-caching-data.html

Тут сразу нужно оговорится если вы захотите проверить работу Yii2 memcache**d** напрямую, т.е.

в Yii2

```
    \Yii::$app->cache->set('mykey', 'value');
```

в произвольном файле

```
    $m = new Memcached();
    $m->addServer('localhost', 11211);
    var_dump($m->get('mykey'));
```

У вас ничего не получится т.к. компонент Cache Yii ( /yii2/caching/Cache.php ) методом buildKey так сказать "нормализует" ключи ( описание метода есть в классе ), но можно для теста сделать так

в Yii2

```
    $cache = Yii::$app->cache;
    $keyStr = 'cache_test';
    $key = $cache->buildKey($keyStr);
    $cache->set($keyStr, 'This is mem test!');
    $get = $cache->get($keyStr);
    var_dump($get , $key); // дампим результат из кеша и сгенерированный ключ ( копируем его )
```

в произвольном файле

```
    $m = new Memcached();
    $m->addServer('localhost', 11211);
    $result = $m->get('242c9254b0a4b5ea5c7f0e000f668408'); // Вставляем полученый ключ

    var_dump(unserialize($result));
```

Далее собственно ближе к сути, **мы хотим хранить сесии в нашем мемкеше**, для этого идем обратно в конфиг и добавляем после настроек кеша следующее

```
    'session' => [
                'class' => 'yii\web\CacheSession',
                //'cache' => 'cache',
            ],
```

Теперь для работы с сессией будет заюзан класс CacheSession ( /yii2/web/CacheSession.php наследуется от Session  /yii2/web/Session.php ) и можно создать нашу сессию

```
    \Yii::$app->session->set('Mysession', 'Mem session');
```

И собственно тут у меня возник некий конфуз, ибо

```
    \Yii::$app->session->get('Mysession'); // Вернет нам значение сессии
    $_SESSION // К моему удивлению так же содержал в себе эту сессию
```

Но на самом деле ничего страшного здесь нет, $_SESSION уже не хранится на сервере в папке tmp как по умолчанию, теперь $_SESSION хранится в мемкешед.

Все дело в том что класс CacheSession переопределяет некоторые методы
класса Session ( в подробности работы вдаватся не буду, можно впринципе пройтись по этим файлам и посмотреть ) в т.ч. getUseCustomStorage(), так же класс Session имеет метод **registerSessionHandler()**
который вызывается при откритии сессии, метод open(), в Session и вызывает в этом случаи getUseCustomStorage() который был переопределен, собственно после этого и происходит магия переноса $_SESSION в мемкешед, функция **session_set_save_handler()** ( http://php.net/manual/ru/function.session-set-save-handler.php ) переопределит методы работы с сессией на пользовательские.

После этого если мы сделаем так $_SESSION['mysession'] = 'value' ( так же как и в методе Session set() ), после открытия сесиии медодом Session open(), сессия будет хранится в нашем кеше.

Надеюсь мои изысканя будут кому-то полезными